# Unable to use FileProvider in Android studio

Tags: java, android, android-fileprovider

I am trying to use FileProvider for file authority (so that other apps could use that authority as their target for requests). The manifest looks like this:

```
        <activity
            android:name=".CrimePagerActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".CrimeListActivity">
        </activity>
        <provider
            android:authorities="com.example.criminalintent.fileprovider"
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.provider.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/files" />
        </provider>
```

but when I try to build the app:

```
process: com.example.criminalintent, PID: 4598
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider androidx.core.content.FileProvider: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Missing android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS meta-data
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7191)
...
```

What is `andoird.support` package (I have `android.provider`) and how can I get that package as dependency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your manifest entry, replace:

```
android:name="android.provider.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
```

with:

```
android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
```